# Implementation of own fast fourier transform algorithm does not work

Tags: matlab, fft

I have found and customized algorithm for fast fourier transform. The algorithm is below:

```
function X = myFFT(x)
   %only works if N = 2^k
   N = numel(x);
   xp = x(1:2:end);
   xpp = x(2:2:end);
   if N>=8
      Xp = myFFT(xp);
      Xpp = myFFT(xpp);
      X = zeros(N,1);
      Wn = exp(-1i*2*pi.*((0:N/2-1)')/N);
      tmp = Wn .* Xpp;
      X = [(Xp + tmp);(Xp -tmp)];
   else
     switch N
       case 2
          X = [1 1;1 -1]*x;
       case 4
          X = [1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 -1i; 1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1i]*[1 0 1 0;1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1;0 1 0 -1]*x;
       otherwise
          error('N not correct.');
     end
   end
end
```

The algorithm above is stored in an .m file named myFFT.

I want to use the code for two subsequent signals:
h1=sin(t2) and for time t2=0:1:255;

I recall the myFFT function in another .m file in this way:

```
x=h1;
X11 = myFFT(x);
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in myFFT (line 18)
           X = [1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 -1i; 1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1i]*[1 0 1 0;1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1;0 1 0 -1]*x;

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);

Error in myFFT (line 7)
    Xp = myFFT(xp);
```

Honestly, I have no idea how to fix it. Could you please help me?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try with `X11 = myFFT(x(:));`, flattening `x` to a column vector

Comment: @Brice: That flattening should happen inside the `myFFT` function.

Comment: @Chris Luengo : Perhaps. But then, there should be a clear specification of what the function is supposed to do (what kind of data in; what kind of data out). Should row vectors as input trigger an error, be processed normally as you suggest, or considered as N independent row vectors of size 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the multiplication of a 4x4 to a 1x4 matrix. The variable `x` need to be transposed.

```
   function X = myFFT(x)
       %only works if N = 2^k
       N = numel(x);
       xp = x(1:2:end);
       xpp = x(2:2:end);
       if N>=8
          Xp = myFFT(xp);
          Xpp = myFFT(xpp);
          X = zeros(N,1);
          Wn = exp(-1i*2*pi.*((0:N/2-1)')/N);
          tmp = Wn .* Xpp;
          X = [(Xp + tmp);(Xp -tmp)];
       else
         switch N
           case 2
              X = [1 1;1 -1]*x';
           case 4
              X = [1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 -1i; 1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1i]*[1 0 1 0;1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1;0 1 0 -1]*x';
           otherwise
              error('N not correct.');
         end
       end
    end
```

then test it with

```
t2 = 0:1:255;
myFFT(sin(t2));
```

Comment: It gives me the same error and yes, x is a 1x4 matrix for N = 4

Comment: remember to put the  '    , transpose operator on the x variable ! You are multiplying a 4x4 to a 1x4, that's why it failed

Comment: I did it, and it still gives me the same error. You can test it on your own, it will give you the same error.

Comment: try to call myFFT([1 2 3 4]) to test. I just run it

Comment: `'` is the ctranspose operator, the transpose operator is `.'` !

Comment: but sill your answer should work, since `x` is not a complex array.

Comment: It gives me this error:

    Error using  * 
    Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in myFFT (line 18)
           X = [1 0 1 0; 0 1 0 -1i; 1 0 -1 0;0 1 0 1i]*[1 0 1 0;1
           0 -1 0;0 1 0 1;0 1 0 -1]*x;

    Error in zkouska (line 16)
    X=myFFT([1 2 3 4]);

Comment: @FrantaMraz, have you read the answer of farbiondriven ? If you do not change your code, it's not really a suprise to get the same error. You still have not transposed the x array.

Comment: I did it as he has written, and it still gives me an error I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: Just read the error of your previous comment and tell me where you see the `x.'`.

Comment: There is nothing to change in the initial code; the function however is meant to work on column vectors (and does not have any input checking on that). `myFFT(sin(t2(:)));` should work.